# Leaflet circle names in array not showing up (circles1 not defined)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to read the names of some circles from and array.

Here is the code:

```
var latLong = [{
  "circleName": "circle1",
  "lat": 5.895763,
  "lng": -1.150556
}, {
  "circleName": "circle2",
  "lat": 5.899817,
  "lng": -1.150689
}];

var circles = [circle1, circle2, circle3];

latLong.forEach(function(coord) {
  var circles = L.circle(coord, {
    color: 'green',
    fillColor: '#fff',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 70
  }).addTo(mymap);
});
```

I am getting the error ... circle1 is not defined.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, you're initializing an array (`var circles = [circle1, circle2, circle3];`) with 3 variables in it. Maybe you intended `var circles = ['circle1', 'circle2', 'circle3'];`. It's not clear what you are trying to do by the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use objects `circles = {}` and bracket notation `circles[coord.circleName]`

```
var latLong = [{
  "circleName": "circle1",
  "lat": 52.895763,
  "lng": -1.150556
}, {
  "circleName": "circle2",
  "lat": 52.899817,
  "lng": -1.150689
}];

var circles = {};

latLong.forEach(function(coord) {
  circles[coord.circleName] = L.circle(coord, {
    color: 'green',
    fillColor: '#fff',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 70
  }).addTo(mymap);
});

console.log(circles.circle1) // or circles['circle1']
```